# Show images in grayscale in Nativescrpt

Tags: css, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm traying to show images in gray in my nativescript app. But it seems to not work.

I use this in my class:

```
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
    filter: grayscale(1); /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
```

But the images are shown with full color... Is there a trick to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS filter attributes are not supported, use [nativescript-image-filters](https://github.com/BradMartin/nativescript-image-filters) plugin.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-image-filters
```